# Sphinx - use custom Jinja2 ChoiceLoader to load templates in specific order

Tags: python, jinja2, python-sphinx

My problem is that I need to load jinja2 templates from a python package that I'm sharing across other repos and applications. My local sphinx theme templates will be extending these shared templates.

In flask I did something like this

```
# Load common templates
template_loader = jinja2.ChoiceLoader([
    app.jinja_loader,
    jinja2.PackageLoader('my_shared_templates', 'templates')
])
app.jinja_loader = template_loader
```

I'm having quite a bit of trouble trying to do something similar in sphinx. I have been looking into writing a sphinx extension to accomplish this but haven't gotten anywhere. I was hoping someone had enough Sphinx experience where they could point me in the right direction for how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using a sphinx extension was a backwards way to go about this. I ended up with a much simpler solution.
In my `conf.py` file I just added the package to the `templates_path` setting.

```
import my_shared_templates
import os
path = os.path.dirname(my_shared_templates.__file__)
path = path+'/templates'
# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = [path, '_templates']
```

My templates in `/_templates` inherit from my base in `my_shared_templates`.